# How to float.Parse or TryParse to a single Console.WriteLine in c#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm new to programming and c# language. In the code bellow i'm trying to get used to coding and test stuff and see how it works.

```
        //excercise with variable y
        int y=2;
        Console.WriteLine("Given y = 2");
        Console.WriteLine("y++ : {0}", y++);
        Console.WriteLine("The value of y is now {0}", y);

        Console.WriteLine("Trying again y++: {0}", y++);
        Console.WriteLine("The valuee of y is now: {0}", y);

        Console.WriteLine("++y : {0}", ++y);                // ++ y Directly prints out y+1
        Console.WriteLine("The value of y is now: {0}", y);

        Console.WriteLine("y++ : {0}", y++);
        Console.WriteLine("The value of y is now : {0}", y);
        x += y;
        Console.WriteLine("lets add x and y: {0}+{1}", x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("A line with no calculations\n");

        y *= 99;
        Console.WriteLine("y *= 99 is: {0}", y);
        y /= 50;
        Console.WriteLine("y /= 50 is : {0}", y);
        y %= y;
        Console.WriteLine("The remainder of y is: {0}", y);

        Console.WriteLine("Lets see the value of y now: {0}", y);
        Console.WriteLine("++y is now : {0}", ++y);

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
```

At the following line i want it to be float like 11.88. But only for this line. I would usually do it with the variable but i'm wondering how to do it this way too.

```
y /= 50;
Console.WriteLine("y /= 50 is : {0}", y);
```

So could it be something like `Console.WriteLine(float.Parse("y /=50 is: {0}",y);`

Thank you guys for helping me!

Comment: Off-topic, but as a way to help you learn the language you may want to change your lines that are viewing `y++` and `++y` to something more useful like `Console.WriteLine("y++ changes y from {0} to {1}", y, y++);`.. See [this example](https://ideone.com/Q0F7Lm)...

Comment: you might want to take a look at the line where you add `x` and `y` as well :) Currently you are storing the sum in the variable x and print x and y to the console, but not the sum.

Comment: Nice tip , thanks alot. All of you guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is cast y to a float, then the division operation should similarly yield a float:

`((float)y)/50`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
Console.WriteLine((float)y/50);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(y/50f);
```

Because `50f` is actually a float literal, `y` will be automatically converted to float. The second option looks better for me.

**Added**: actually the second option is preferred because it has only one type converstion: `y` from int to float.
First option has two: the first on is explicit cast to float - `(float)y`, and implicit cast of `50` to float, because float can be diveded only by float.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
Console.WriteLine("y /= 50 is : {0}", (float)y/50);
```

I think what you were missing is that

```
y /= 50;
```

is nothing else than a short version of

```
y = y/50;
```

Edit:
also like pointed out in the comments y/50 is an integer division. To convert the result to the float datatype, you need to either convert the divisor, or the whole result to float by using.

Comment: Those operations will lose decimal precision because y is an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Whilst casting to a float will fix your issue, your question was how to do `float.Parse` on a single line. The code you provided doesn't have any strings to parse but if it did then [`float.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does return a float so you can just use that directly in your calculations

```
float.Parse("1")/2.0f;
```

However, you should think if it is really necessary always to include everything on one line. The code you have provided is probably fine to be on one line but it can help the maintenance and upkeep of code by striving to keep it as readable as possible. Anywhere a line of code begins to just become lengthy, you may wish to start splitting it up into multiple lines or with temporary variables.